# Matlab: 1D Numerical PDEs without Loops

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

So, currently I am trying to find the numerical solutions for the berger equation, $u_t+u∗u_x=0$. The numerical solution to this equation is:

$u^{n+1}_j=u_n^j−\frac{Δx}{Δt}u^n_j(u^n_j−u^n_{j−1})$
I wrote code on Matlab that computes this. As you can see, there is only one for-loop in the code. However, my u matrix extremely large, the algorithm becomes slow. Is there a way for me to use no loops at all. I was thinking about using the command cumsum, but I am not sure how to integrate that to my program. Please look at my code. Thanks.

```
dx = 0.9;
dt = 0.9;
tf = 10;
l = 10;
xstep = [-1:dx:l];
tstep = [0:dt:tf];
uinit = zeros(length(tstep),length(xstep));


%%Setting Initial and Boundary Conditions
bc.left = @(t) 2;

bc.right = @(t) -1;

ic = @(x) ...
    2*(x<=0) ...
    -1*(x>0);

uinit(1, :) = ic(xstep);
uinit(:, 1) = bc.left(tstep);
uinit(:, end) = bc.right(tstep);


%% Numerical method part

for c=1:(length(tstep)-1) 
   uinit(2:end -1, c+1) = uinit(2:end -1, c) - dx/dt*(uinit(2:end -1, c).*(uinit(2:end-1, c) - uinit(1:end-2, c)));

end

surf(xstep,tstep,uinit)
```

Comment: Because u_t depends on u_(t-1), I do not think you can parallelize it.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to know thanks